# Understanding static variable initialization in Java

Tags: java

```
public class InstanceBuilder {

    private static final InstanceBuilder INSTANCE = new InstanceBuilder();

    private static String name = null;

    private InstanceBuilder() {
        System.out.println("Setting cons()");
        name = "Testing";
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("value is " + InstanceBuilder.getName());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Setting cons()
value is null
```

Why does it print value as `null` even though I have set the `static` variable in constructor and it is called as expected. If I try to print in constructor, it is printing `Testing`, but if I call from `public static` method, it is `null`. I know if I change it to `INSTANCE.name`, it works.
But I want to understand why it is not working if I directly access `static` variable since same copy should be shared.
What I am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Because the value of name is getting modified after the constructor invocation as per the declaration order.**

Lets see what is happening:

1) When you call `InstanceBuilder.getName()`, `InstanceBuilder` class is getting loaded. As part of that process `INSTANCE` and `name` instance variables are getting initialized.

2) While initializing `INSTANCE`,

```
private static final InstanceBuilder INSTANCE = new InstanceBuilder();
```

constructor of `InstanceBuilder` class is getting invoked & `Setting cons()` statement is getting printed and `name` variable is initialized with `Testing`.

3) Next `name` is again getting re-initialized with `null` due to the below statement

`private static String name = null`;

so when the method call returns to `Driver` class, value of `name` is `null` and `null` is getting printed. So even though `name` is declared as `static`, static has no role in that context.

**Note:**

Check the below link on the order of which class members should be declared

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#1852

Answer (score 0):

Here value is null because static initialization occurs as its declare in order,
So First your

```
`private static final InstanceBuilder INSTANCE = new InstanceBuilder();`
```

code execute and assign value to "testing", then your

```
 `private static String name = null;`
```

code exceute and override value to null(as static variable have coppy per class only), so final value will be null.

So here this behavior is just beacuse of order of execution of static variable

Comment: Thanks, Got it where I was wrong from your explaination.